# Encountering Uncaught ReferenceError: renderFromCache is not defined

Tags: kiwi-tcms

After i upgrade to from v5.1 to v5.3.1 the search plans, runs and cases are not loading upon checking the console on inspect element i encountered this problem, even though all the files are loading properly.

[Uncaught ReferenceError: renderFromCache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL1Y0.png)

Answer (score 1):

5.3.1 at this point is a very old version, nearly 2 years old. Try upgrading to the latest version (8.5 ATM), upgrade in steps between the intermediate versions, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I tried to update it to v8.5 but the error still occur, follow the upgrade path on the document.

"
Uncaught ReferenceError: renderFromCache is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (search.js:72)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
"

Comment: upon further investigation, i tried to copy the settings of our dev-server on my local since we are using haproxy, found out that the problem is not on the kiwi, the problem is on our server and on the settings of our haproxy

Comment: Sounds like your HAproxy is caching a JavaScript file ?